# Hexadecimal Java Recursion Issue

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive program that converts base 10 numbers to any base 2-16.I have created all the code except my hexadecimal conversion is a bit off. Below is the code

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    public class convertBase
    {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{


    String choice;
    int base;
    int number;
    String newNum;

Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.println("Please enter the Number you would like to convert " );
    number = console.nextInt();

System.out.println("Please enter the new base: ");
    base = console.nextInt();

    if (base>=2 && base<=16)
    {

        System.out.println(convert(number,base));
    }
    else if (base<2||base>16)
    {
        System.out.println("You entered an incorrect base. Base must be an integer between 2 and 16.");
    }



    //}
    }
    public static String convert(int number, int base)
    {

        char[] hexDigits = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};//character array for hexidecimal 


        int quotient = number / base;//we divide the number by the base
        int remainder = number % base;//take the modulous for the remainder

        if(quotient == 0&&base!=16) // base case
        {
            return Integer.toString(remainder);   //to String so we can manipulate it for the reverse
            //Ex. in binary 56 is 110111 reversed is 111011
        }
        if(quotient == 0&&base==16) // base case
        {
             String hex = hexDigits[remainder]+"";

             return hex;//this is to call the number of the remainder and relate it to the characters

        }
        else
        {
            return convert(quotient, base) + Integer.toString(remainder);
            //calls itself to constantly convert until if conditions are met
            //We need to keep the remainder in order to solve for the next values
        }
```

When I run the program testing 255 to a base 16, F15 is my programs result when FF is the correct answer. I feel like the issue is in the return statement and I have done everything I can think of to fix it such as a huge return statement, breaking up the data into smaller strings, and writing a whole different program that simply did not work because it was not recursive. If anybody spots my error I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In the last else branch you call Integer.toString() for the remainder:

```
    else
    {
        return convert(quotient, base) + Integer.toString(remainder);
        //calls itself to constantly convert until if conditions are met
        //We need to keep the remainder in order to solve for the next values
    }
```

It should probably be `return convert(quotient, base) + convert(remainder, base);`

Answer (score 0):

I see this small mistake in your code, and hope that is it (all). Please change:

```
convert(quotient, base) + Integer.toString(remainder);
```

..to:

```
convert(quotient, base) + hexDigits[remainder];
```